# resetPassword issues in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I sent enrollment email to the user and when he enters password and other details I'm trying to reset the password but it is throwing error

```
uncaught error extpected to find a document to change
```

[image]

As you can see in the mage

I've subscribed to the user record

my code

```
this.route('enroll', {
        path: '/enroll-account/:token',
        template: 'enroll_page',
        onBeforeAction: function() {
            Meteor.logout();
            Session.set('_resetPasswordToken', this.params.token);
            s = this.subscribe('enrolledUser', this.params.token).wait();
        }
    }),
```

After I'm displaying form and on the submit event

```
onSubmit: function(creds) {
            var options = {
                _id: Meteor.users.findOne()._id,
                name: creds.name
            }
            var token=Session.get('_resetPasswordToken');
            Meteor.call('updateUser', options, function(error, result) {
                if(!error) {
                    Accounts.resetPassword(token, creds.password, function(error) {
                        if (error) {
                            toastr.error("Sorry we could not update your password. Please try again.");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            toastr.error("Logged In");
                            Router.go('/');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    toastr.error("Sorry we could not update your password. Please try again.");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            this.resetForm();
            this.done();

            return false;
        }
```

Everything  is working fine but resetpassword callback is not triggering and the above error is displaying in console.

**my token is get deleted from the user record and I'm able to login using login form but**

From the docs

```
Reset the password for a user using a token received in email. Logs the user in afterwards.
```

I'm not able to automatically login after resetting the password,above error is throwing

What am I missing here?

Comment: in case if anyone looking for meteor ready code for reset password link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539216/how-to-reset-password-in-meteor-application/49996724#49996724

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.subscribe('enrolledUser', this.params.token).wait();
```

here you're subscribing using resetPassword token

when you call `Accounts.resetPassword` method the method will reset the password and delete the token from user record.

So your subscription is lost and there are no records available in client side to modify
(That is waht the error `Expected to find a document to change`)

Instead on first subscription save the user Id and subscribe to the user record using `Id`

so the subscription will not be lost

```
path: '/enroll-account/:token',
        template: 'enroll_page',
        onBeforeAction: function() {
            Meteor.logout();
            Session.set('_resetPasswordToken', this.params.token);
            s = this.subscribe('enrolledUser', this.params.token).wait();
        },
        onAfterAction:function(){
               if(this.ready()){
                  var userid=Meteor.users.findOne()._id;
                  Meteor.subscribe("userRecord",userid);
               }
        }
```

Comment: did you try this?  It's not working for me.  Same error.  How does Meteor do it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do something like as follows in your publication. This worked for me (but mine was a slightly more involved query than this).

```
Meteor.publish('enrolledUser', function (token) {
  check(token, String);
  return Meteor.users.find({
    $or: [{
      _id: this.userId
    }, {
      'services.password.reset.token': token
    }]
  });
});
```

From the docs, it says

> Reset the password for a user using a token received in email. **Logs the user in afterwards.**

So basically, you have to subscribe to the logged in user after the fact as well. A little silly, but whatever.

Comment: The solution above is not compatible with `meteorhacks:fast-render`. Still get the _Uncaught Exception: expected to find a document to change_ error. Once fast-render was removed, everything works as desired. 

I'm using FlowRouter and template-based subscriptions which I thought might work. Some server-side logging shows that the enrolledUser publication is always successfully populated. However, something isn't occurring correctly re the client-side interaction. If anyone has a work-around for this fast-render race condition, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Workaround was to remove the subscription.  This form can work with just the token, getting the user was just for fancy to show user's name and email.