# How to reset password in meteor application

Tags: meteor, passwords, reset, accounts

I am building a Meteor application and am using the `oaf:accounts-entry` package to handle my user registration & authentication. I am working on the reset password function right now. However, when I click on "email reset password link", the application doesn't email me anything. Can someone help me or point me to instructions on how to configure the reset password function for the `oaf:accounts-entry` package? After doing a google search, I could not find instructions on how to configure it. The relevant packages I have installed are:

- `oaf:accounts-entry`
- `accounts-password`
- `email`

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The password reset functionality should be working as it's provided by the package.

Have you properly configured your emails smtp settings and tested that your application is dispatching emails properly?

https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-3-smtp-configuration/5

Comment: Hi - Yes, I have configured the email. The email function actually works for other parts of my application, but not reset password...

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**: Using Meteor JS 1.6.1.1, package required are ***accounts-ui, accounts-password***

To make *forgot password* link visible in the signup/sign in a widget, you need to do add little configuration in a file at location `ROOT_FOLDER/client/main.js`. The code is as below,

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_AND_EMAIL"
});
```

If you do not choose `passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_AND_EMAIL"` and choose something like `passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"`, you won't be able to see *forgot password* option in the signup widget. (No one will tell you this, I discovered this weird scenario myself. Still, I wonder why MDG team did this? )

At Server end you also need to add little code at location `PROJECT/server/main.js` just outside `Meteor.startup(()=>{});` to provide an email template for reset password link. Below is the code you need to adjust some properties yourself.

```
var username = 'you_id@gmail.com'; 
var password = 'your password';
var server = 'smtp.gmail.com';
var port = '465';

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtps://' +
encodeURIComponent(username) + ':' +
encodeURIComponent(password) + '@' +
encodeURIComponent(server) + ':' + port;

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

Accounts.emailTemplates.from = 'support_team@yourappname.com';


Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = 'APP NAME';

Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword = {
  subject(user) {
    return "Reset Password Link.";
  },
  text(user, url) {
    return `Hello! 

    Click the link below to reset your password.

    ${url}

    If you didn't request this email, please ignore it.

Thanks,
APP Team.
`
  },
  html(user, url) {
    // This is where HTML email content would go.
    // See the section about html emails below.
  }
};
```

**STEP 1:**

See if you are able to view forgot password on the signup widget as below.

[image]

**STEP 2:**

When you click "*forgot password*", you should be able to view below popup at same widget location as below.

[image]

on valid Email entry, you must see a success full notification and most importantly you must receive a mail for reset password link as below.

[image]

**Step 3:**

When you click on the link, you can see a new window with a popup as below (**NOTE:** You must click the link before given token expiry time).

[image]

Voila!!! just add a new password and you automatically login to given page. Everything is already provided to us as discussed above by Meteor. You just need to configure the stuff and get it running.