# MeteorJS accounts-password password reset email

Tags: meteor

I'm using the default settings of the accounts-password package for MeteorJS. Using the default {{> loginbuttons}}, I'm able to add login functionality out of the box. The one thing that doesn't seem to be working is the reset password feature. I've configured the MAIL_URL variable correctly as I can send emails using the email package and when I click on reset password, it pops up on the UI to say that an email was sent. However I am not getting any emails sent to my inbox. 
I'd be grateful for any help you give me on this matter. I think it's probably something small I'm missing...

All the best

Comment: When you reset, do you see any link on the server side ? Check in Ur terminal.

Comment: No I don't see anything outputted to the console

Comment: You may find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539216/how-to-reset-password-in-meteor-application/49996724#49996724

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that you can call to send this:

```
Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail(userId, [email])
```

http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendResetPasswordEmail

Call it from your server code to verify that it works (or not). If this does, it is perhaps something in your styling or html that is preventing it

Comment: Thanks for the answer...on the server I have Meteor.methods({
    'emailUser': function() {
        return Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail(1234456, ['name@email.com']);
    }
}); which I call from the client. Is there any way of getting any better debug information. Does this method return anything that I could output to the console?

Comment: The next step is to look at your smtp server. If it sends other emails it sounds like it's working. Perhaps the spam filters are blocking this email. You probably need to look at the smtp server logs, or the spamassasin logs to see where it's failing